# How to evenly space 3 concatenated fields in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I have three fields that I concatenated into one field, but when I run the query the result-set is correct, but they are not evenly spaced within the one field.  How would I space them neatly and correctly.  Thank-you for the help.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),Book)+ Space(2) + '(' + CONVERT(varchar(30),Year)
+ ')' + Space(2) + '(' + CONVERT(varchar(30),Print) + ')' As  'Film Description', Genre,
Cost
FROM Film
Order By Year DESC, Book ASC
```

Comment: When would Year ever be anything other than 4 characters?

Comment: @Aaron - What as that about future-proofing some minutes ago? :) Personally, I plan to live until 24,123

Comment: @Richard of course, the Y10K bug. Well even if you were proofing for the year 10000 you shouldn't need 30 characters unless you are spelling out `the year ten thousand`...

Comment: Don't try to do display formatting in your query. Do it in the front end application or reporting tool instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `VARCHAR` ignores trailing spaces, you need to use a different data type that doesn't (e.g. `CHAR`). A few other comments:

- be careful about using reserved words such as `year` and `print` as column names
- be careful about using `'single quotes'` as alias delimiters (`[square brackets]` are more future-proof and harder to muddle with string literals)
- you should use the schema prefix (e.g. `dbo.Film`)

```
DECLARE @Film TABLE(Book VARCHAR(255), [Year] INT, [Print] VARCHAR(255));

INSERT @Film 
SELECT 'a', 2012, 'hello there this is at least 30 characters, right?'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'this must be at least 30 characters too, right?', 2011, 'b';

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(20), Book)
 + SPACE(2) 
 + '(' + CONVERT(CHAR(4),[Year]) + ')' 
 + SPACE(2) 
 + '(' + CONVERT(CHAR(30), [Print]) + ')' 
 As [Film Description]
FROM @Film
Order By [Year] DESC, Book;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert(Char(` instead of `Convert(Varchar(`
Varchars have the spaces stripped off..